# jQuery Slider With Loading Bar?

Tags: jquery, html

Are there any jQuery sliders with a loading bar?  I have seen them on a couple sites but I don't remember which those were.  The closest thing I can think of would be the Orbit slider but that's a radial loading bar and I'm just looking for a flat line at the bottom..

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try Presentation Cycle

Cycle is a script that supports image presentations to easily display multiple images. This script supports a lot of effects and the cycling of html elements. Presentation Cycle is a variation on the functionality of Cycle. Instead of generating a list of numbers that are clickable Presentation Cycle generates a progress bar that shows when the new slide will appear.

```
http://www.gayadesign.com/scripts/presentationCycle/
```